# Check output of subprocess python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

hey i'm updating my script , I've changed os to subprocess for now, but i don't know how to check the output? I want to check is it empty or what its in. Script just execute other program or list of sentences.

```
"""
Created on Sun Jan  8 18:52:57 2017

@author: MarcGrad
"""
import sys
import subprocess


syntax = '''
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Syntax:        python find_by_sentence.py *file1.txt
*List of sentences (column of) 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''
if len(sys.argv) != 1:
        print(syntax)
        sys.exit()

open_file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')

list_of_sentences = []

for sent in open_file:
    list_of_sentences.append(sent.rstrip())
counter = 0
for word in list_of_sentences:
    counter += 1
    print(counter,word)
    subprocess.check_output("esearch -db protein -query %s | efetch -format fasta >> results_seq.txt" % (word), shell = True)

print('done :)')    
open_file.close()
```

Comment: It looks as if you are concatenating the output to a file (results_seq.txt), so why do you expect it to be any output?

Also, the returning value of `subprocess.check_output` is the output, so you can do some validations on that (you can also pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to get stderr)

Comment: just wanna know when the sentence given have no results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start a process it has automatically open 3 file descriptors (you can look at it like on one-way communicating channel):

- `STDIN` - Used for input from user (e.g. used when entering password to SSH)
- `STDOUT` - The text which is used as standard otuput of the application (e.g. channel for printing messages on console)
- `STDERR` - Same as STDOUT but used fo error messages.

You can redirect output (also input but that doesn't apply to your question) to files (in other words you "disconnect" the console and "connect" a file). For redirecting are specified those symbols: `>` and `>>` (for more information look at the https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171025/what-does-do-vs). The command `ls -l >> file.txt` will write output of `ls -l` and write anything on the console (because it's "disconnected")

The `result = subprocess.check_output(...)` takes commannd and "connect" its `STDOUT` into the `result` variable. But you are running this command: `esearch -db protein -query %s | efetch -format fasta >> results_seq.txt` and if you look at the end you'll see `>> results_seq.txt`. So output of your command is already "connected" into file `results_seq.txt` and cannot be saved inside the `result` variable.

Now you can use those approaches:

1. Run your command as is and then open file `results_seq.txt` and look at the content

   ```
   subprocess.check_output("esearch -db protein -query %s | efetch -format fasta >> results_seq.txt" % (word), shell = True)
   with open("results_seq.txt", "r") as f:
        result = f.read()
   ```
2. Do not use redirection in the command and save it on your own in Python:

   ```
   result = subprocess.check_output("esearch -db protein -query %s | efetch -format fasta" % (word), shell = True)
   with open("results_seq.txt", "wb") as f:
        f.write(result)
   ```
3. Use `tee` which is utility allows redirect output to file and also keep it on console

   ```
   result = subprocess.check_output("esearch -db protein -query %s | efetch -format fasta | tee -a results_seq.txt" % (word), shell = True)
   ```

At the end of any of those examples you will have saved output of your command saved in the variable `result`

Comment: but instead of string i get b' ' for every iteration :(

Comment: The `subprocess.check_output` returns bytes for convertig it into str just call `decode()` e.g. `result.decode()`